# What is the meaning of "used to meet" in this passage?

Tags: meaning

i am not english native speaker, i am italian.

*What is the meaning of "used to meet" in this passage?*

> Only U.S. Dollars or U.S. Treasury bills, floating rate notes, notes
>   or bonds are acceptable and must be deposited by a clearing member
>   applicant during the application approval process. All securities must
>   be denominated in multiples of $5,000. Stripped securities and
>   securities dated prior to January 1, 1973, are not acceptable. TBonds
>   may not exceed 10 years time to maturity. Interest is not paid on U.S.
>   Dollar deposits. If U.S. treasuries are deposited, the market value of
>   such securities, less any applicable haircut, must be at least equal
>   to the minimum requirement. For example, U.S. T-Bills with a par value
>   of $505,000, market value of $502,000 and no haircut may be **used to
>   meet** the $500,000 Base Guaranty Fund requirement.

Comment: The phrase to analyze is not _"used to meet"_ but rather _"may be used"_ . _"To meet"_ is the infinitive complement of _used_.

Comment: Please tell us: did you think that _used to_ in the cited phrase was employed to describe an habitual action in the past?

Comment: No wooden spoon **may be used to cut** meat.  No emergency flare may be used to light a cigar.

Answer (score 1):

The verb "to meet" has many nuanced definitions, including here:

> [**meet**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meet) (v): *3. Fulfill or satisfy (a need, requirement, or condition)*

Some examples:

> Does the wine *meet* with your approval?
>
> The car *meets* with all the latest government regulations.
>
> I want to get a loan but unfortunately I don't *meet* the minimum income requirement.

In this context the passage is saying that these particular funds *can be used to satisfy* the stated condition.